# Inkscape flat icon dropshadow

Tags: graphic-design, inkscape

I need a plugin for Inkscape so that I can create dropshadow icons.

What I specifically need is that it should use a path and give long dropshadow at a specified angle.

An example for the expected result is:

[image]